# Django bakery ImportError: Could not import 'p'. The path must be fully qualified

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to export my site as flat files with django bakery.

I made a dummy site with a sample polls app and I get this error when I run `python manage.py build`

```
  File "python3.6/site-packages/bakery/management/commands/build.py", line 112, in handle
    self.build_views()
  File "python3.6/site-packages/bakery/management/commands/build.py", line 240, in build_views
    view = get_callable(view_str)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/utils.py", line 25, in get_callable
    raise ImportError("Could not import '%s'. The path must be fully qualified." % lookup_view)
ImportError: Could not import 'p'. The path must be fully qualified.
```

I followed all their instructions correctly:

polls/views.py:

```
from bakery.views import BuildableTemplateView

class HomePageView(BuildableTemplateView):

    template_name = "home.html"
    build_path = 'index.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
    'bakery'
]
BUILD_DIR = '/Users/me/Downloads/build/'

BAKERY_VIEWS = (
    'polls.views.HomePageView'
)
```

mysite/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

polls/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
from polls.views import HomePageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

Maybe it is something related to the urls? But I can't see what. The site works fine in the browser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is because the setting should be a tuple, which requires a comma.

```
BAKERY_VIEWS = (
    'polls.views.HomePageView',
)
```